# Installing ArcGIS Engine Runtime via image copy?

Tags: installation, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-engine

We have about 400 ArcGIS Runtime Engine 10.4.1 licences, where we will install on devices for emergency. These devices already up and running and using ArcGIS Engine Runtime 9.3. The time we are going to upgrade these device to the new version the time is critical for us to do that very fast. So we cannot just authorize each device separately.

Is there any way to do that via image copy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use image include the software installed, but for authorization :
*single use license  : you should authorize each device separately

- Concurrent use license : you can specify the server I.P on the image also and test it .